# Why do we need the [python-3.x] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Python 2.* has reached end of life 7 months ago. Why do we need the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag? I noticed that many questions are tagged [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) without being tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). I think in most cases they should be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Maybe it's time to disable the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag, at least for new questions.

Comment: Because when Python 4 comes out with some breaking changes, you will have trouble finding appropriate questions and solutions. I don't know about tagging rules in python tag, but in some other tags it is customary to add general tag and edit questions that don't have it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't *disable* a tag. It's available or it is not, and we will not be removing it, because Python is not static and there probably will be a Python 4, one day.

While it may be preferable to use [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) for new questions, it's not a big problem if only [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) was used. Python experts follow either anyway. Just edit the post to add the tag and move on.

Answer (score 6):

I would also like to point out that while Python 2.* might have reached end of life, that does not mean that all software written in it is has now disappeared from the Earth.

Many humans will still need to support it, will work in legacy systems, or will be in various situations where they can't switch to Python 3, and they deserve to be able to specifically tag their questions with Python 2 if they need to.